# get ajax responseText javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to the responseText from an onstateready in an XMLHttpRequest ajax call. currently all I am getting out of my responseText is "object event" I ran it through a String() and now when I do a typeof on it, it returns string. My console header is showing a response of the content desired, but my responseText is not getting it. what am I doing wrong?

I should note this does not involve jquery, keeping it native.

```
                   function getPatterns() {
                        var url = document.URL;
                        var httpRequest;

                        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { // modern browsers
                            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
                            httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(responseText){
                            responseText = String(responseText);
                            console.log('responseText: '+ typeof responseText); // returns "string"
                            console.log('responseText: '+ responseText); // returns "object event"

                            // process the server response
                        };
                        httpRequest.open('GET', url+'&showpatterns=true');
                        httpRequest.send();
                    }
```

Comment: The parameter passed to [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/readystatechange) *event* is an event object, not a string!  Your `responseText` is located at `httpRequest.responseText`.

Comment: Also, I believe it's only available when `httpRequest.status == 200 && httpRequest.readyState == 4`.

Comment: That was my problem I was leaving out the httpRequest. thanks a lot!