# Ajax OnFailure function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I have an AJAX.RouteLink which has the following AJAXOptions

```
new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                OnFailure = "OnFailure",
                OnSuccess = "OnSuccess"
            })
```

My OnFailure method looks like this

```
function OnFailure(ajaxContext) {
        var response = ajaxContext.get_response();
        var statusCode = response.get_statusCode();

        var elem = document.getElementById('message');
        elem.innerHTML = 'Sorry, the request failed with status code' + statusCode;
    }
```

Problem is, when it gets called I get this error

```
TypeError: ajaxContext.get_response is not a function
```

In the watch list I can see that the `responseText` in `ajaxContext` is html.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is that JavaScript or some ASP.NET language? If it's supposed to be JavaScript, then it has syntax errors in it.

Comment: If the code is supposed to be java script, then it has some syntax errors . See this for some closure : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835417/get-ajax-responsetext-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that ajaxContext doesn't have a get_response method.  It must be an old version of the object whose example I was looking at.

Since I wanted the status code, I just used the ajaxContext.status property.